# Script not running properly

Tags: linux

Here is what I have to do
“ Make a script to find all old, unused files, larger than 1 megabyte, starting at a directory supplied by the user (default: /tmp).  Make “old” be more than a month by default, but allow the user to change it.  Similarly make the  size be one megabyte by default, but allow the user to change it.”

I have attempted several scripts but can’t seem to get this right. Here is what I wrote:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
find /home/usr/local/temp -atime +31 –size +1M
# Then to allow permission for everyone
chmod u+x Filename
```

Answer (score 0):

In `–size` you seem to be using the Unicode en dash instead of an ASCII hyphen. Otherwise your command is fine.

Consider adding `type -f` to find only files, not directories.

```
find /home/usr/local/temp -atime +31 -size +1M -type f
```

Also, by "allow the user to change it", I think it means allow the user to change the parameters, like 10 days and 5 MB, not giving the user write permission.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding what exactly is going on in the script. Like visualizing, how would you describe it?

Comment: `find /dir` lists all files and directories in /dir. `-atime` means access time, and `+31` means at least 31 days ago. Similarly with `-size`. `-type -f` means find files only.

`chmod` controls access to a file or directory. `u` means user, `+x` means give execute permission, `+w` write permission  and `+r` read  permission.

Comment: i tried putting this as my code but still it says " No such file or direrctory"

Comment: !#/bin/bash       find /home/usr/local/temp -atime +31 -size +1M -type f

Comment: Do you have a directory called `/home/usr/local/temp`? Also it's `#!` not `!#`.